# Why is terra::resample() failing on this remote environment but working on my laptop?

Tags: r, terra, nlcd

When I run terra::resample() on land cover data taken from [NLCD](https://www.mrlc.gov/data/nlcd-2019-land-cover-conus)
using this code

```
library(terra)
lc <- rast("path/to/lc_data")
test_match_crs <- rast(crs = crs(lc), res = 80, ext = .1*ext(lc)) 
values(test_match_crs) <- 1:ncell(test_match_crs)
plot(test_match_crs)

resample_lc <- resample(lc, test_match_crs, "near")
print(resample_lc)
plot(resample_lc)
```

it works fine on my laptop (the first `sessionInfo()`)
However, when I try to run on in a high performance environment (the 2nd `sessionInfo()`).
the `resample_lc` has only values of zero.  There is no error or warning.

I have tried to match the version of GDAL and terra in the remote environment to my laptop's versions.  Any thoughts on which aspect of the remote environment is causing terra::resample() to fail?

laptop info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dy
lib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dy
lib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] terra_1.5-34    nvimcom_0.9-131 devtools_2.4.2  usethis_2.1.3  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.9        magrittr_2.0.3    pkgload_1.2.3    
 [4] R6_2.5.1          rlang_0.4.12      fastmap_1.1.0    
 [7] tools_4.1.2       pkgbuild_1.2.0    sessioninfo_1.2.1
[10] cli_3.1.0         withr_2.4.3       ellipsis_0.3.2   
[13] remotes_2.4.1     rprojroot_2.0.2   lifecycle_1.0.1  
[16] crayon_1.4.2      processx_3.5.2    purrr_0.3.4      
[19] callr_3.7.0       codetools_0.2-18  fs_1.5.0         
[22] ps_1.6.0          testthat_3.1.0    memoise_2.0.0    
[25] glue_1.6.2        cachem_1.0.6      compiler_4.1.2   
[28] desc_1.4.0        prettyunits_1.1.1
> gdal()
[1] "3.2.2"
```

Cluster info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib64/libblas.so.3.4.2
LAPACK: /usr/lib64/liblapack.so.3.4.2

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] terra_1.5-34    nvimcom_0.9-131 devtools_2.4.3  usethis_2.1.6  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.9        magrittr_2.0.3    pkgload_1.2.4    
 [4] R6_2.5.1          rlang_1.0.2       fastmap_1.1.0    
 [7] tools_4.2.0       pkgbuild_1.3.1    sessioninfo_1.2.2
[10] cli_3.3.0         withr_2.5.0       ellipsis_0.3.2   
[13] remotes_2.4.2     rprojroot_2.0.3   lifecycle_1.0.1  
[16] crayon_1.5.1      brio_1.1.3        processx_3.5.3   
[19] purrr_0.3.4       callr_3.7.0       codetools_0.2-18 
[22] fs_1.5.2          ps_1.7.0          testthat_3.1.4   
[25] memoise_2.0.1     glue_1.6.2        cachem_1.0.6     
[28] compiler_4.2.0    desc_1.4.1        prettyunits_1.1.1
> gdal()
[1] "3.2.2"
>
```

Comment: the first thing I would do, to allow for better comparison, is to update terra on your mac so that it matches the version on the cluster; which is the current CRAN version. It is of course possible that it will then fail on both platforms --- but at least we would know more about why that happens. Reporting what is returned by `gdal()` could also help

Comment: @RobertHijmans Thank you!  I added `gdal()` and matched the GDAL and `terra` versions between the two environments.  The problem persists on the cluster.  The laptop environment is still good, only difference is nicer colors for the categorical data :)

Comment: I guess the big difference now is the R version.  I will try it with R 4.1.2 on the cluster and see what happens, and then maybe go to 4.2.0 on the laptop.